# How do you number equations

Tags: support

I have an answer that has a number of equations. Within the text of the answer I just want to refer to the number of the equation. I saw it on an answer somewhere, but I can find such an answer now. What is the markup?

Comment: Welcome to meta! We have a nice [sandbox](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here-test?s=1|0.3937) which is occasionally a good self-teaching guide, and almost always made dirty by our doodles. But you can find all things formatting there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> 2+2=4\tag{1}

$2+2=4\tag{1}$

Comment: Is there a handy way to autonumber? The [MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.5-latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering) way I found makes things breaky -breaky.

Comment: Never heard of such. Maybe that's because I'm inclined to write comparatively short answers, so manual numbering would suffice.